# URL Re-Write Works, But Removes CSS

Tags: css, url-rewriting

I am using the URL rewrite below on the .htaccess file, and work works wonderfully.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^one/([^/]+)$ /one/two/index.php?profile=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It makes this:

```
http://www...com/one/john
```

into this:

```
http://www...com/one/two/index.php?profile=john
```

However, there is one little problem: all of the CSS is gone.  How can I get the CSS styling to appear?

Comment: Where do the CSS paths resolve to?

Comment: I tried putting the right CSS in the root, but that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use full URLs to link to the CSS, or set RewriteBase to the correct path in .htaccess

```
# Installation directory
RewriteBase /
```

In general, using full URLs (not just for CSS but also images, etc.) is the way to go and will save you a lot of troubles in the long run.

Comment: How does `RewriteBase` have any effect? Perhaps you meant the HTML `base` element...?